# myClass copyWithZone unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

When trying to get a object from an mutable array to et the values for that row in a tableview  I get the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[KCNote copyWithZone:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15589f60'

Below is my code, I had a look about this error and most places talk about issues copying data structures from the object to the new one however the objects contents is just intergers and strings as you can see below.

KCNote.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface KCNote : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger NoteID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Note;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Author;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Date;

@end
```

Code in my view controller for the table.

```
NSMutableArray *Notes;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    Notes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ...
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"notecell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        }
        // Configure the cell...
        KCNote *note = [Notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        UILabel *Author =(UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
        UILabel *Date = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:2];
        UILabel *Note = (UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:3];

        Author.text = note.Author;
        Date.text = note.Date;
        Note.text = note.Note;


        return cell;
}
```

Notes are added to the array using:

```
-(void)getNotes:(NSInteger)courseid{
    [Notes removeAllObjects];
    FMResultSet *s;
    s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM notes WHERE CourseID =?;", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", courseid]];
    //s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM notes;"];
    if ([db hadError]) {
        NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
    }
    while ([s next]) {
        NSInteger NoteID = [s intForColumnIndex:0];
        NSString *Note = [s stringForColumnIndex:2];
        NSString *Author = [s stringForColumnIndex:3];
        NSString *date = [s stringForColumnIndex:4];
        KCNote *note = [KCNote new];
        note.NoteID = NoteID;
        note.Note = note;
        note.Author = Author;
        note.Date = date;
        [Notes addObject:note];
    }
    [self.tbl_notes reloadData];
}
```

Comment: `Notes` is declared without a type, and capitalized, which looks wrong. Also, accessing your cell views using tags is a code smell. You're better off just exposing them as properties of your cell class.

Comment: Which line does the exception occur on? Set an exception breakpoint to find out

Comment: It crashes at return cell

Comment: `note.Note = note;` is the problem. `note.Note = Note;` is right. Anyway DO NOT use UpperCamelCase for property and variable names.